# WatchOS 6.2.6 - Can not test sanbox In-app purchase with independent app

Tags: watchos, in-app

I have problem when test in-app purchase sanbox in independent WatchOS application
Enviroment: Xcode 11.5 and WatchOS 6.2.6 - Swift UI project

The problem is when i call function buy the product, the WatchOS (both simulator and real device) alway shows message: **unable to purchase app sign in with your apple id from the apple watch app on your iphone.**
[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yldsP.png)

1. I tried to build and test in TestFlight mode also, its same result.
2. Changed AppleID in Iphone (pairing with watch) but not effect.
3. When debuging In simulator and device, i can get informations about IAP packages (include price and description) created on the Itune connect.

Anyone meet the problem before, please help me resolve it.
Many thank !

Comment: I’m having this same issue right now. Did you ever find a solution?